# Managing ASP.NET Sessions

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session-state

I am looking for a way to refresh certain values in sessions when an event take place.

For example navigation tabs may be a cached in the session for each online user and when the arrangement of the tabs are changed, I need to propagate the change in all active sessions.

Is there a way to access all Active Sessions and make changes to them? if not, what workaround do you suggest?

Comment: sounds like you should use cache instead of session https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsbfdd8c%28v=vs.140%29.aspx

Comment: Something like your navigation should not be in your session or really even in a cache, explicitly at least. You're likely doing this because you can't work with multiple models in a view and you need someway to retrieve and generate your nav. The correct method is to use child actions. (The result of the child action could be cached)

Comment: I cannot use cache, since the navigation menu is personalized for each user. There is a bit of verification, permission check and database query involved in order to get the final list of menu items, this is why I am keeping the results in Session to prevent redoing all of this for every request.
Now I would really appreciate if someone can help with the actual question.

Comment: They were trying to "help you with the actual question" especially in light of your request for suggesting a workaround. If you followed up on @ChrisPratt  advice you would see that you can cache by individual user using something like the [OutputCacheAttribute] which can be varied by ContentEncoding, Header, Param, Custom. You'd simply invalidate a session stored key menuid for a user on a request and then have a child action with OutputCacheAttribute build and cache your menu. Thereafter you would have that users session request that child action varied by menu id param.

Comment: The navigation menu is just an example not the actual problem or the only item on the list of requirements. What I need is a way to access/modify active sessions. Also it would be nice to provide code example for solution your suggesting, I am having a hard time following it.